# Making energy from revolving doors

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

I know it is possible to create energy from revolving doors but is there a certain amount of speed needed for it to create it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create energy, but you could harvest energy from the people that are pushing on the doors.

There's no theoretical lower limit to the speed.  But any harvesting you do will increase the drag on the door.  The more energy you try to extract, the more drag and difficulty users will experience.

You might want to do an analysis and see how much energy it's possible to extract.  You'll have a certain number of people moving through.  If you increase the drag, some of those people might avoid the door.  If you can only harvest (as an example) 10 watt-hours, would it be worth the expense of adding mechanisms to extract it?

Comment: The speed of any practical revolving door is limited by a governor. Normally that would be a brake that turns the work done by people on the door into heat. In theory, any fraction, up to 100% of the energy that normally would be wasted as heat, could be turned into electric power instead without the users of the door noticing any difference at all. In practice of course, there still would some energy lost as heat.

Comment: Re, "would it be worth the expense...?" I'm imagining some kind of electronic device that wants to be attached to the revolving part of the door. If you could power it by means of maybe a friction roller that presses against the ceiling, that might be _much_ less expensive than powering it by other means.

Comment: Yes, some sort of micro-power harvester, with a battery/capacitor for storage would certainly be possible.  If you just need milliwatts to run something, that seems reasonable.  You could always use a gearing system to change the speed range to whatever is useful for the generator.